# Multiple index in pandas series in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a table like this:

```
key1 | key2
---------------
0    | a, b, c
---------------
1    | d, e, f
---------------
```

I would like to convert it to like:

```
key1 | key2
------------
0    | a
------------
0    | b
------------

0    | c
------------
1    | d
------------
1    | e
------------
1    | f
------------
```

Any simple way in **Pandas**? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Is `key2` `['a', 'b', 'c']` or `'a, b, c'`?

Comment: @Alexander It's a list of strings.